# JsonObject<List<string>> can't add any data

Tags: c#, mysql, json, entity-framework

I tried writing to db using Pomelo.EntityFramework.Mysql with the following code, but it failed. (I know that this is not the fault of Pomelo.EntityFramework.)

```
public class Element
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public JsonObject<List<string>> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
Element element = new Element();
element.ElementId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
element.Tags = new List<string>() { "user" };
element.Tags.Object.Add("newtag");
```

jsonobject only converts "user" to json.(["user"])

What did I make a mistake?

**EDIT**

i try rewrite code of Pomelo.JsonObject

just changed this code.

```
public string Json
{
    get { return SerializeObject(Object); }
  set
  {
    try
    {
      Object = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
        ? default(T)
        : DeserializeObject<T>(value);

      _originalValue = value;
    }
    catch
    {
      Object = null;
      _originalValue = string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

from

```
public string Json
{
  get { return _originalValue; }
  set
  {
    try
    {
      Object = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)
        ? default(T)
        : DeserializeObject<T>(value);

      _originalValue = value;
    }
    catch
    {
      Object = null;
      _originalValue = string.Empty;
    }
  }
}
```

Now it works perfectly.

Comment: Why create such a class? JSON.NET can serialize any object. Why not create a `List<string> Tags{get;set;}` ? Btw since you store a Guid in `Id` change the type to `Guid` as well.

Comment: If you really have to store properties as JSON objects, use JArray, not JObject. JSON doesn't have lists, it has dictionaries/objects and arrays

Comment: thanks for your comma
Thanks for the comment.

Pomelo.EntityFramework supports only Pomelo.JsonObject.
Is there a way to use Json.Net?